# Execution time elapsed error while query from that large Data Table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using TextFieldParser to read a CSV file then adding rows to a temporary data table. I performed sqlbulkcopy from temporary datatable to fill 05 columns of my main data Table ("Sim VehRecord"). My main data Table has 09 columns. I made 04 queries on previously copied 5 columns to fill rest 04 columns of the main data Table. I have almost 5 million rows. Command execution time upto bulkcopy was ok. But once i made subsequent 4 queries it always gave me the "Execution time elapsed" error. I understand the error lies in the structure of the query. But i am dead stop here, could not make any headway to solve. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tblReadCSV As New DataTable()

        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Sim_Time")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Veh_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Link_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Lane_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Position")


     Dim csvParser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Aus\Result Output\Rome A - 2D_001.fzp")
        csvParser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        csvParser.SetDelimiters(";")
        csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

        For j = 0 To 16
            csvParser.ReadLine()
        Next

        Try

            While Not (csvParser.EndOfData = True)
                tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields())
             End While
    Dim str As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Main Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Dim SqlDataAdapter2 As New SqlDataAdapter            
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand    
            con.ConnectionString = str
            con.Open()
            SqlDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = cmd
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            ''cmd.CommandTimeout = 2700
            cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [Sim VehRecord]"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim bulkcopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[Sim VehRecord]"
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Sim_Time", "Sim Time (sec)")
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Veh_No", "Veh No")
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Link_No", "Link No")
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Lane_No", "Lane No")
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Position", "Position (m)")
            bulkcopy.BatchSize = 50000
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(tblReadCSV)
            bulkcopy.Close()

           cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET [Speed (km/hr)] =
                            (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),3.6* COALESCE (([Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - MIN (sv.[Position (m)]))/NULLIF(([Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] -MIN (sv.[Sim Time (sec)])),0),0)) 
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv
                            WHERE
                            sv.[Veh No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Veh No]
                            And
                            sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
                            And
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]), 

                            [Veh no of Leader] =
                            (SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] 
                            AND 
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)]= [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No]= [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            ORDER BY sv.[Position (m)] ASC),

                            [Veh no of Follower] =
                            (SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] 
                            AND 
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)]= [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No]= [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            ORDER BY sv.[Position (m)] DESC),

                            [Headway (m)] = 
                            (SELECT FORMAT(MIN(sv.[Position (m)]),'N2','en-us')
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            AND
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]) - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)],

                            [Density (veh/km)] =
                            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Veh No])
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv
                            WHERE
                            sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - 15 And
                            sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] + 15)"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Close()
            tblReadCSV.Dispose()

           Sim_VehRecordTableAdapter.Fill(Main_DataDataSet.Sim_VehRecord)
           DataGridView1.DataSource = Main_DataDataSet.Sim_VehRecord
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried splitting your `UPDATE` query into multiple queries? You seem to be doing a huge number of sub queries.

Comment: You are using the default CommandTimeout of 30sec.  If need more time, just change your SqlCommand.CommandTimeout.

Comment: Try your Update query in SSMS and look at the explain plan for hints on missing indexes.

Comment: If i even do single sub query by omitting rest three it gives the same error. i tried with  CommandTimeout = 0. But with  no fruitful result.

Comment: Does your table have the proper indexes?

Comment: I have [Record ID] column which is auto increment clustered primary key